# How to earn the Tag Editor badge?

Tags: support, badges, edit-badges

I do not understand how you can earn the [Tag Editor badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/73/tag-editor). What do you have to do and where?

Comment: @SPYDR no, that's not what the tag is for. Please read the tag wiki. Thanks. (e.g. if the question was "How close am I to earn the Tag Editor badge" then it would fit.)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When you click on a tag (such as the ones visible under this very question — [support](/questions/tagged/support), [badges](/questions/tagged/badges), and [edit-badges](/questions/tagged/edit-badges)), you will see a short excerpt from the tag's "Tag Wiki", which is a short description of what that tag is for and how it relates to the site:

> [image]

Beneath that excerpt is a link titled "edit". It is on this page that you'll be able to *improve* the description of a tag in order to earn this badge.

Comment: 20k reputation need to win this badge?

Comment: Not at all- your edits will just need to be peer-reviewed before going live.

Comment: Alditis, badges are not a match game. You don't *win* badges. You just *earn* badges.

Answer (score -1):

Link "*improve tag wiki*" does not exist anymore.

Steps to get badge **"Tag Editor"**:

- Click any tag (`javascript`,`angularjs` or some other)
- On top of the page locate and click link **"improve tag info"**
- Edit tag information
- Click button "Save Edits"
- Wait for edits approval

Comment: You couldn't just suggest an edit to the other answer?

Comment: "improve tag wiki" just became "edit", it's still there.